# Image Slider on 2013

Tags: search-results, image-display

Is there a way to change (edit) the default image slider format in the SharePoint 2013 Search Web Part?

I would like to change how it looks slightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "configure it", but you can write custom CSS that overrides how it looks, e.g., by adding Script Editor web part to the same page and adding your overriding CSS there.

Comment: Can't he just edit the display template associated with that to edit how the slider is displayed?

Comment: Thought "change how it looks slightly" is easier with CSS. Obviously if it's more throrough modificatioin or if Slider is used on multiple pages and same "slight" tweak needs to be in all places, then editing the Display Template makes more sense.